# How to copy function callback?

Tags: c++, function, callback, copy, swap

I have a Timer class that calls function pointer on timeout. The problem that this Times should be able to be copied (instances of it can be swapped in array). After copying the m_callbackOwner became invalid.

So, how to deal with this problem? How to implement callbacks to allow copying?

```
#pragma once

#include "common/Function.h"
#include "helpers/Utils.h"

template<typename TimeoutCallbackOwner, typename TimeoutCallback>
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer() : m_interval(0), m_value(0), m_callbackFunction(nullptr) {}

    void setCallback(TimeoutCallbackOwner *cbOwner, TimeoutCallback cb)
    {
        assert(cbOwner && cb);
        m_callbackOwner = cbOwner;
        m_callbackFunction = cb;
    }

    void update(double dt)
    {
        if (m_interval < 0 || isEqual(m_interval, 0))
        {
            return;
        }

        m_value += dt;

        if (m_value >= m_interval)
        {
            m_value = 0;

            if (m_callbackOwner, m_callbackFunction)
                CALL_MEMBER_FN(m_callbackOwner, m_callbackFunction);
        }
    }

    void setInterval(double interval)
    {
        m_interval = interval;
        m_value = 0;
    }

    double interval() const
    {
        return m_interval;
    }

    double value() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    bool isRunning() const
    {
        return m_value != 0;
    }

private:
    double m_interval;
    double m_value;

    TimeoutCallbackOwner * m_callbackOwner;
    TimeoutCallback m_callbackFunction;

};
```

Comment: What is `CALL_MEMBER_FN` ? And what types do you provide for the templates ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Show the definition of  a type you use as `TimeoutCallback`  parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `if (m_callbackOwner, m_callbackFunction)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @ElderBug What, you don't think the OP overrode `friend operator,`?